# How to solve ValueError: x and y must be the same size issue on Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-regression, spyder

I'm trying to do a linear regression, however I keep running into the same problem of "ValueError: x and y must be the same size". I'm very confused, and have been on every single website there is to try to fix it. If anyone would know that would be a massive help. I don't understand what to do.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score, mean_absolute_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#load datatset
df = pd.read_csv('Real_estate.csv')
X = df[['transaction date', 'house age', 'distance to the nearest MRT station','number of convenience stores', 'latitude','longitude']]
y = df['house price of unit area']
x= df.iloc[:,0:-7].values
y= df.iloc[:,1:].values
x, y = np.array(x), np.array(y)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x, y)
model = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( x, y, test_size  = 0.4)
sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(x_train)
x_train_std = sc.transform(x_train)
x_test_std = sc.transform(x_test)
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(x_train_std, y_train)
y_pred = regr.predict(x_test)
r_sq = model.score(x, y)
print("Intercept: ", regr.intercept_)
print("Coefficients: \n", regr.coef_)
# The mean squared error
print("Mean squared error: %.2f" % mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
##Model evaluation
print("Mean absolute error: %.2f" % mean_absolute_error(y_test,y_pred))
print("Coefficient of determination: %.2f" % r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
y_pred = model.predict(x)
print('predicted response:', y_pred, sep='\n')
plt.scatter(x_test,y_test, color="black")
plt.plot(x_test, y_pred, color="blue", linewidth=3)
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.show()
```

This is my code but I don't know understand what's going wrong. I'm trying to use 7 columns, including the y value. I'm a beginner to Python, so I apologize if this is a very silly question. Thank you.

Comment: This is hard to read. Just copy and paste the code to the question and select the part you want to show as code and then press Ctrl+K and it will be formatted correclty.

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error (again as formatted text).

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.plot(x_test, y_pred, color="blue", linewidth=3)
```

Both arguments need to be of the same shape, but y_pred is prediction over entire x, instead of x_test

change

```
y_pred = model.predict(x)
```

to

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: Or alternatively change `plt.plot(x_test...)` to `plt.plot(x...)`.